# Improper Integrals and Parameters

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I was studying the convergence of the following improper integral that depends on the parameter $C$:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{Cx}{x^2+1} - \frac{1}{2x+1} \, dx$$

I know it converges for some real value $C$, but I cannot find it. Does anyone know some path? I don't want the complete solution (as it would be very boring not to get to it by myself), just a tiny nudge.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : you need to exploit the fact that you have a subtraction between the two terms because each term separately doesn't converge since they are $ \approx \frac{1}{x}$ as $x \to \infty$

---

Summing up the two fractions you obtain

$$\frac{Cx}{x^2+1} - \frac{1}{2x+1} = \frac{Cx(2x+1)-x^2-1}{(x^2+1)(2x+1)} = \frac{x^2(2C-1)+Cx-1}{(x^2+1)(2x+1)} $$

What about if you choose $C = \frac{1}{2}$ ?

---

If $C = \frac{1}{2}$  the limit ratio

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{2}x-1}{(x^2+1)(2x+1)}}{\frac{1}{x^2}} $$

is equal to a finite value as you can easily verify so it means they grow approximately at the same rate.

Comment: Yes, I know, but what I ignore is how to do this...

Comment: @see my update :-)

Comment: When $x \to \infty$, the whole fraction would tend to 0?

Comment: yes but it would be faster, it goes as $\frac{1}{x^2}$ which converges

Comment: I see that, but how can you prove it? I mean, algebraically. Because I don't know how to show that, after $C=1/2$, the initial integral converges.

Comment: @Uri Toti See my edit

Comment: Thank you very much! That really clarified everything.